# .NET: Generate a JWT from ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I have spent the last few days trying to understand how authentication works in .NET apps. There's a lot of documentation available (much on this very website!) which claims to explain it, and it all starts off saying something like "It's easy! Now that you've configured your IIncomprehensibleConfigurableIdentityFactory to use the proper IdentityDismodulatingExtensions, simply add your KeyProvider to the LockedStorageService (link to official .NET documentation that might as well be written in Sumerian)..."

So, I have what I believe is a simple question, and I will try to explain it using normal words as much as possible. I expect that whoever answers it will come in to tell me that all my assumptions are wrong and furthermore I have committed some grave offense by even asking; my only request is that you explain this to me using terms that my tiny brain might manage to comprehend, so that I can perhaps figure out how to do this thing correctly.

---

In the Blazor app I am working on, I sometimes need to call to another API. I would like to secure these API calls using JWT tokens (or another type of straightforward-ish security protocol) and I would like to send these tokens with each request, containing the ID and claims details of the specific user which the application is making the request on behalf of.

So what this entails, I believe, is accessing the user who is making the call, which we can do by accessing the current `HttpContext` (this part is already working) and calling `.User`, which returns a `ClaimsPrincipal` object. It seems to me that I should be able to get a JWT from that...somehow, right? It appears the [process can work the other way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128228/how-to-retrieve-claimsprincipal-from-jwt-in-asp-net-core) at least. So how do I do that? In terms of code:

```
public static string GetTokenForUser(ClaimsPrincipal user)
{
  // what goes here?
}
```

Comment: There's a problem with this question. First, to create a JWT token programatically, you have to decide what authentication is used, whether it's just HMAC or maybe an RSA/ECDSA. This raises another issue, if the token is supposed to be generated **at the client side** (Blazor), you need the key at the client, which could potentially be a security issue (or not, depending on how you design it in details).

Comment: As for actual code, there are examples available.g. [here](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2017/10/jwt-tokens-between-net-and-nodejs.html) or [here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/01/19/net-6-create-and-validate-jwt-tokens-use-custom-jwt-middleware).

Comment: Thank you! These are some of the most helpful examples I've seen so far; I have no strong feelings as to what authentication to use so I'll probably try HMAC and see how that works.

Comment: Do you have any update on this question now?

Comment: Yes, I will edit it which what I've found soon